# Inequality between product of two numbers.

Tags: calculus, inequality

$k,l\in N$ and  $k \ge l\ge2$ then prove $(k+1)^{k+1}(l-1)^{l-1}\ge k^kl^l$.

From examples it is ok but unable to proof I tried to proof in different ways e.g. by taking ration but all in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the well-known inequalities

$$(1 + 1/n)^{n+1} > e,\\(1 - 1/n)^{n-1} > e^{-1}.$$

Then

$$\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{k^k}= k(1+1/k)^{k+1} > ke \geqslant le > l(1 - 1/l)^{1-l}= \frac{l^l}{(l-1)^{l-1}}\\ \implies(k+1)^{k+1}(l-1)^{l-1} \geqslant k^kl^l$$